# Open image from URL instead of local file input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm modifying an open source script that takes a html file input and starts doing things with from there:

```
    $fileInput.change(function(event) {
        var file = this.files[0];
        file && openFileAsImg(file);
        this.value = '';
    });
```

I'm trying to open the image from a URL instead, such as http://myapp.com/images/87654.jpg

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does the external server send appropriate [CORS headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for retrieving the image via AJAX?

Comment: I guess I could modify them coz I serve the image blobs from App Engine Blobstore

Comment: really not 100% clear what you are trying to do, can interpret this several different ways

Comment: I guess I just want to retrieve an image via Ajax, like ComFreek suggested.